# Dynamics 365 CRM Web API. @odata.nextLink is too long

Tags: dynamics-crm

I received data from Dynamics 365 through Web API and extracted url from @odata.nextLink field. But I received 414 Error (The request URL is too long) when I use this url and send request to Dynamics.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please provide your initial url? The next page url is built using the original one. Is there a way to make it shorter?

Comment: After some research, I found that the url has too many identifiers to select in the filter, and I will rewrite this logic.